# Need help to understand mysql error log

Tags: mysql, wordpress

MySQL data bases crash/go down every ten days. I have been reading the following error log file where it says: Database was not shut down normally! (But I don't know why)

It indacates some tables crashed... How can I find out why?

Our site is a WordPress project under AWS EC2 instance, with ubuntu, apache server and mysql.

```
    150604 14:38:32 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
    150604 14:38:32 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
    150604 14:38:32 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 14:38:32 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 5163 ...
    150604 14:38:32 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 14:38:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150604 14:38:32 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2022756426
    150604 14:38:32  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
    InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
    InnoDB: buffer...
    InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2022758706
    150604 14:38:32  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
    InnoDB: Progress in percents: 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
    InnoDB: Apply batch completed
    150604 14:38:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    150604 14:38:34 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 2022758706
    150604 14:38:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    150604 14:38:34 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    150604 14:38:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    150604 14:38:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    150604 14:38:34 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
    150604 14:38:34 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_blogs' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 14:38:34 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_blogs'
    150604 14:38:34 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_sitemeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 14:38:34 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_sitemeta'
    150604 14:38:52 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 14:38:52 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_options'
    Killed
    150604 14:38:58 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
    150604 14:38:58 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
    150604 14:38:58 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 14:38:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 5346 ...
    150604 14:38:59 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 14:38:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150604 14:38:59 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
    150604 14:38:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    150604 14:38:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    150604 14:38:59 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    150604 14:38:59 [ERROR] Aborting

    150604 14:38:59 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

    150604 14:38:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
    150604 15:01:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
    150604 15:01:26 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 15:01:26 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 6338 ...
    150604 15:01:26 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150604 15:01:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150604 15:01:26 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2022758706
    150604 15:01:26  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
    InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
    InnoDB: buffer...
    InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2022759772
    150604 15:01:26  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
    InnoDB: Progress in percents: 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
    InnoDB: Apply batch completed
    150604 15:01:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    150604 15:01:27 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 2022759772
    150604 15:01:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    150604 15:01:27 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    150604 15:01:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    150604 15:01:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    150604 15:01:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
    150604 15:01:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp__3wp_broadcast_broadcastdata' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp__3wp_broadcast_broadcastdata'
    150604 15:01:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_blog_versions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_blog_versions'
    150604 15:01:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_commentmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_commentmeta'
    150604 15:01:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_comments' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_comments'
    150604 15:01:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_options'
    150604 15:01:30 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_postmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:30 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_postmeta'
    150604 15:01:30 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:30 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_posts'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_registration_log' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_registration_log'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_term_relationships' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_term_relationships'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_term_taxonomy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_term_taxonomy'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_terms' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_terms'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_usermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_usermeta'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_users'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_order_items' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_order_items'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_termmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_woocommerce_termmeta'
    150604 15:01:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './prod_gremyo/wp_wslusersprofi

les' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150604 15:01:31 [Warning] Checking table:   './prod_gremyo/wp_wslusersprofiles'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-related problems, those that can be solved with code. Have you read the part of the error message that says **"Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool"**?

Comment: So this seems to be a RAM issue?

Comment: If someone knows a better community where I can post this I'll thank him/her for the info ;)

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) deals specifically with issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

try to solve, the firsts warnings and 'The InnoDB memory heap is disabled', and then look their performance.